# Combine Query(that contains a subquery) with another Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Both query's below work independent of each other. I need to combine them into one, and accomplish the following.

1. Count the number of dispatches (DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED) for an employee for a date range.
2. Count the number of completed dispatches for an employee for a date range. I'm already setup to handle this in php. Doing it in the query would be a nice to have but not necessary.
3. Count the number of Clearing Action Codes that are 10,35,80 for  an employee for a date range.

Code:

```
/*  1  */
SELECT  COUNT(INCIDENT_NUMBER) AS NTFR
FROM ETA
WHERE CLEARING_ACTION_CODE IN ('10-Trouble Cleared','35-False Report','80-No Trouble Found - C.O.')
AND INCIDENT_NUMBER IN (SELECT INCIDENT_NUMBER
                        FROM  HDESK
                        WHERE DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED = 'Yes' 
                        AND CUST_EMPLOYEE_ID = 'n9950298' 
                        AND REPORTED_DATE_TIME_RAW_VALUE
                        BETWEEN 1420510400 AND 1420906799)


/* 2 */
SELECT INCIDENT_NUMBER, STATUS,DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED 
FROM HDESK
WHERE DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED = 'Yes' 
AND CUST_EMPLOYEE_ID = 'n9950298' 
AND REPORTED_DATE_TIME_RAW_VALUE
BETWEEN 1420510400 AND 1420906799


/*This is what I came up with that works. */
/* 3 */
SELECT H.INCIDENT_NUMBER, H.STATUS,DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED , CLEARING_ACTION_CODE
FROM ARADMIN.WIN_LT_RPTG_HELP_DESK H, ARADMIN.WIN_LT_RPTG_ETA_APPT_INFO E
WHERE H.DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED = 'Yes' 
AND H.CUST_EMPLOYEE_ID = 'n9950298' 
AND H.REPORTED_DATE_TIME_RAW_VALUE BETWEEN 1420510400 AND 1420906799
AND H.INCIDENT_NUMBER = E.INCIDENT_NUMBER (+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(e.INCIDENT_NUMBER)as NTFR,
       h.INCIDENT_NUMBER, 
       h.STATUS,
       h.DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED,
       COUNT(e.CLEARING_ACTION_CODE) as CLEARING_ACTION_CODE
FROM ETA e 
INNER JOIN HDESK h 
on e.INCIDENT_NUMBER= h.INCIDENT_NUMBER
WHERE h.DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED = 'Yes' 
                        AND  e.CLEARING_ACTION_CODE 
  IN ('10-Trouble Cleared','35-False Report','80-No Trouble Found - C.O.')

                        AND h.CUST_EMPLOYEE_ID = 'n9950298' 
                        AND h.REPORTED_DATE_TIME_RAW_VALUE
                        BETWEEN 1420510400 AND 1420906799

GROUP BY e.INCIDENT_NUMBER,e.CLEARING_ACTION_CODE,h.STATUS,h.DATA_CANNON_DISPATCHED
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Khurram. I ran this and "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function" was returned.

Comment: @MattJamison See my edits i have added group by clause

Comment: appreciate the reply unfortunately this errored too.

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: @MattJamison add remaing columns into group by statement and check it

Answer (score 0):

For given emplyoee and period you can use this query. I am not sure what you wanted in some parts, 
please try to remove `distinct` if something is not OK.

If you need table like: Id - Dispatches - Completed - Codes 
then query an be easily converted by adding `id` in `select` part and adding `group by` clause.

```
select 
    count(distinct incident_number) dispatches,
    count(decode(data_cannon_dispatched, 'Yes', 1)) completed,
    count(distinct clearing_action_code) codes
  from eta e join hdesk h using (incident_number)
  where substr(e.clearing_action_code, 1, 3) in ('10-', '35-', '80-')
    and cust_employee_id = 'n9950298' 
    and reported_date_time_raw_value between 1420510400 and 1420906799
```

Test data and results:

```
with eta as (select 1 incident_number, '10-Trouble Cleared' clearing_action_code from dual
  union select 2, '10-Trouble Cleared' from dual
  union select 3, '80-No Trouble Found - C.O.' from dual),
hdesk as (
  select 1 incident_number, 'Yes' data_cannon_dispatched, 
    'n9950298' cust_employee_id, 1420510400 reported_date_time_raw_value, 
    5 status from dual
  union select 2, 'Yes', 'n9950298', 1420510401, 6 from dual
  union select 3, 'No', 'n9950298', 1420510402, 6 from dual
  union select 3, 'No', 'aqq50298', 1420510403, 0 from dual)
select 
    count(distinct incident_number) dispatches,
    count(decode(data_cannon_dispatched, 'Yes', 1)) completed,
    count(distinct clearing_action_code) codes
  from eta e join hdesk h using (incident_number)
  where substr(e.clearing_action_code, 1, 3) in ('10-', '35-', '80-')
    and cust_employee_id = 'n9950298' 
    and reported_date_time_raw_value between 1420510400 and 1420906799
```

Result:

```
DISPATCHES COMPLETED  CODES
---------- ---------- ---------- 
         3          2          2
```

Notes:

- it would be better to store clearing action codes and clearing action descriptions in different tables, this way you don't have to allways store whole these strings in table.
- the way you store dates is somewhat unreadable ;-)
- it's allways simpler for person answering when you add some input and output data.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b406/1)

Comment: your first select gave a ORA-00905: missing keyword. As for the 2nd reply where did you come up with the results? Are you using an online sql test page? sqlfiddle maybe?

Comment: **1)** query works for me, just copied and pasted it **2)** no, test data is in subqueries: `eta as (...` and `hdesk as (...` I'll try to produce sqlfiddle and add to answer.